# ElasticSearch - last write win behaviour without specifying a version

Tags: elasticsearch

It would seem that partial updates to documents using the `update` API will fail if the document was change before the update was applied:

> To avoid losing data, the update API retrieves the current _version of
>   the document in the retrieve step, and passes that to the index
>   request during the reindex step. If another process has changed the
>   document between retrieve and reindex, then the _version number won’t
>   match and the update request will fail.

It then goes on to say that you can supply `retry_on_conflict` which would retry the write if a conflict does occur:

> For many uses of partial update, it doesn’t matter that a document has
>   been changed...
>
> This can be done automatically by setting the
>   retry_on_conflict parameter to the number of times that update should
>   retry before failing; it defaults to 0.

So if I use the `update` API with `retry_on_conflict` of say 3, without supplying the `_version` field, that ES will internally fail once (if a conflict does occur), and then retry and overwrites the value that it was conflicting with?

It would seem so, because

> ...the update API adopts a last-write-wins approach by default

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_updates_and_conflicts

Note: I'm using ES 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's about it. A clarification regarding `retry and overwrites the value that it was conflicting with` statement: the conflict was with the **version** of the document (not an arbitrary field within your document), let's make this clear, and it was an internal conflict between ES GETing the document and actually writing the new (updated) document (these two actions being part of the `_update` operation).

And it is not overriding a value it is conflicting with, it is another update operation that will succeed as soon as the versions checks are ok and, yes, will update the document in the index.

If you need to make sure your updates go **in a certain order** you need to use **version**.

Comment: So, if I have two update operations, A and B, starting at the same time. The ES internal GET retrieves the same version for both A and B. Lets say A completes the update, and updates the version. Now B attempts to write. The version has been updated. A will fail, but it will retry. Whos write will win? A or B? I think the core question is, when a update is retried, is the entire cycle retried? (getting the new version and continuing with the update)

Comment: A already suceeded. B will be retried considering the whole process from the start. That parameter would be useless if it would use the same old version. It would fail every time.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Is there any use to keep retrying multiple times if there is no version info being updated after each failed attempt ?